# Scroll down div programmatically as contents added to it using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have a div that shows progress to the user in JQuery dialog. I have scrollbars to it. What I want is that when I append text (In jQuery code), the div should automatically scroll down and user should able to see the progress. For example

- Initialising,
- Processing records,
- Stock is updated,
- Getting new orders information,
- Processing Orders,
- Orders processed.. on so on

Can someone please help me out how to do this in Jquery? Thank you.

My code where I append div

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../Services/OrderR.asmx/Process",
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify(params3),
  success: function (p) {

    if (p.d.Success == true) {
      status = status + p.d.Message + '</br>';
      $('#divProgressDialog').empty();
      $('#divProgressDialog').append(status);
      return;
    }
    else {
      status = status + '<font color=#FF0000>Error - ' + p.d.Message + '</font></br>';
      status = status + 'Please contact support team.';
      $('#divProgressDialog').empty();
      $('#divProgressDialog').append(status)
      return;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Or, even better, create a snippet for this?

Comment: I have added code Mosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this before BOTH(*) your return;

```
var myHeight = $('#divProgressDialog').scrollHeight
$('#divProgressDialog').scrollTop(myHeight);
```

EDIT : I would have tested this code if you provided a jsfiddle but I think this is all you are missing. Everytime you add content, it calculate the new height the the div and proceed to scroll to the bottom.

(*) = EDIT 2

Comment: Thank you Alexandre. I had to edit this as var mydiv = $("#divProgressDialog");
                                                    mydiv.scrollTop(mydiv.prop("scrollHeight"));

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I appreciate your quick response it solves my problem. :)